# Word choice - Have come to understand / have understood

Tags: tense-agreement

> 1. I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I **have come to understand** the relationship.
> 2. I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I **have understood** the relationship.

Which one is the more natural way to say?

Comment: You can eliminate the problem altogether by shortening your sentence: _I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I do_. Another way to say it: _I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I understand_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the problem altogether by shortening your sentence:

> *I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I do*.

Another way to say it:

> *I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I understand*.

Or, informally:

> *I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I get it.*

If you really want to specify what you now understand, try:

> *I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but now I understand such relationships.*

If you want to emphasize that it took you a long time to figure it out, use the tense in your first example, but try changing the adverb:

> *I didn't understand a friendship between a guy and a girl, but gradually I have come to understand such relationships.*